# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 3799: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv
count=0
trainpath='C:/Users/503183568/Downloads/sample1.csv'
trainpath2='C:/Users/503183568/Downloads/sample2.csv'
with open(trainpath, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    with open(trainpath2,'w',newline='') as outfile:
        trainReader = csv.reader(infile)
        trainWriter= csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in trainReader:
            trainWriter.writerow(row)
```

**I am trying to copy sample1 content to sample2 but getting the error mentioned in heading tried with utf-8 and utf-1252 encodings also but not able to read the content of sample1**
the data which is not able to read is "File Name: D©;" in csv file

Comment: can you show the content of file that you are reading, plus, try to use 'latin' encodingm see if it helps

Comment: Zain Arshad file is having data like "File Name: D©;" this kind of data format i am not able to read

Answer (score 0):

According to specification of UTF-8 the symbol can't start with binary 10. Instead it can start with binary 0, otherwise with bin 110, 1110, 11110, and the remaining bytes will start with first bit 1. But bin 10* is exactly the case of 0x90, which is binary 10010000. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 
That is why your text is not UTF-8. Try another encoding.

The symbol © is hex A9, but not 0x90 (check exact symbols in your text with hex editor). 0xA9 binary 10101001 (in ISO Latin 1). From ASCII extended, value above binary 1000000. All the chars with first first bit set to 1 are extended, and interpretation depend on coding table. The expected UTF-8 value of © is \xC2\xA9 (or binary 11000010 10101001).